# Algolia filter geolocation with radius

Tags: angular, firebase, algolia

I use Algolia for full text search in my Ionic project with Firebase. I'm able to search and filter all objects. But when I use 'aroundRadius', it returns nothing.
If I comment 'aroundRadius' and just use 'aroundLatLng', it returns all the data without caring about the location.
The filed _geoloc with lat and lng also exist in my data.

```
this.index.search(query,{

      filters: filters,
      aroundLatLng: location,
      aroundRadius: radius

    }).then((data) => {      
      console.log(data);
    })
```

Do I need any special configuration for Indice or the syntax is wrong? I followed [this link](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/how-to/filter-results-around-a-location/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. Everithing is ok by codding and result. It retrurns nothing because my current location was so dar awar from the location of objects I was searching. I tried test it with browser and not a real device and it got the incorrent location.